# R - Confusion List / Vector

Tags: r

I'm new with R and I'm really struggling to understand data types.

I have this dataframe:

```
> names = c('First Name', 'Second Name')
> timestamps = c('123,124,125,126', '234,235,236')
> df = data.frame(names, timestamps)
        names      timestamps
1  First Name 123,124,125,126
2 Second Name     234,235,236
```

At this stage, timestamps are characters. Want to transform it into a list, so I do:

```
df$timestamps <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(as.character(x), ','))))
> df
        names         timestamps
1  First Name 123, 124, 125, 126
2 Second Name      234, 235, 236
```

Then I want to create three columns, `count`, `min`, `max`.

```
df$count <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) length(x))
df$min <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) min(x))
df$max <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) max(x))
```

But then it stops working. I want to order it by `count`, and create a `duration` column.

I tried:

```
> df$duration <- df$max - df$min
Error in df$max - df$min : non-numeric argument to binary operator
> df$duration <- lapply(df, function(x) x$max - x$min)
Error in x$max : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> df <- df[order(-df$count),]
Error in -df$count : invalid argument to unary operator
```

If I run

```
> typeof(df$count)
[1] "list"
```

I wanted a `integer`, why not? If I run:

```
> typeof(length(df[1,]$timestamps))
[1] "integer"
```

So `df$count` should be an array of `integer`s, shouldn't it?

Is my approach correct? What data type is the easiest to manipulate? What is the solution to get the `duration` columns and get those ordered.

I hope I can be clear, it is hard to ask a question correctly on something so unclear to me.

Comment: From the creation of the `count` variable onward, try using `sapply` rather than `lapply`.

Comment: ...FWIW, the origin of your confusion is probably the fact that you start out with the `timestamps` variable as a list column in a data frame, which can be done, but is somewhat "non-standard". A more "usual" way to structure that kind of data would be to convert it to a long format with a unique row for each name/timestamp combination, so that your original data frame would have 7 rows (or 8 depending on how you want to handle missing data), not 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that here

```
df$count <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) length(x))
df$min <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) min(x))
df$max <- lapply(df$timestamps, function(x) max(x))
```

You are creating lists which go to the columns of the data.frame df and then your next operations which are intended for vectors do not work.

As joran indicates using `sapply` will return vectors in this case so you will be fine.

You can do:

```
sapply (df, class)
```

to find out the class of each of the columns in your data.frame